# HTML5 Video run event once if currentTime is larger than X

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to trigger a jquery event if a `<video>` is closer than 30 seconds form the end of playback. However, I only want this event to run once, regardless of the position after < 30, if it has already triggered, then don't do so again.

I have the below code which triggers via timeupdate, but it repeatedly triggers for any `currentTime` within 30 seconds from the end of playback.

How can I adjust to only run once? I'm not able to simply stop timeUpdate, as I use this to show the `currentTime` of the video, so this would break.

```
var video = $('#video');

function func() {
    if ( video[0].currentTime > video[0].duration-30 ) {
        console.log('You are less than 30 seconds from the end!');
    }
}

video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    func();
});
```

Comment: Hi Rory, would you mind converting this into an answer, not sure I 100% follow?

Comment: Sure, I added it for you

Comment: Thanks Rory, that's perfect :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a flag to keep track of the state of the event occurring. By default the flag will be false. It will only be set to true when the `currentTime` of the video is less than 30 seconds from the end.

You can now use this flag in your if condition so that it will only ever fire once, like this:

```js
var $video = $('video');
var $p = $('p');
var eventFired = false;

$video.get(0).volume = 0.2; // just for testing

function func() {
  if (!eventFired && this.currentTime > this.duration - 30) {
    eventFired = true;
    $p.show();
  }
}

$video.on('timeupdate', func);
```

```css
p { display: none; }
video {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>You are less than 30 seconds from the end!</p>
<video autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```